# In Elasticsearch, what is the difference between standalone term in query context and term in filter?

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, if I want to search for some documents with exact field value, there are two ways to do this job.

The first one is to use a standalone `term` in `query` context.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {"type_1": 1}
  }
}
```

Or I could use a `term` in `filter` context.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {"type_1": 1}
  }
}
```

These two methods give the same search result. But, is there any difference(in terms of performance) between them?

Comment: As of ES 2.0, there's no more query and filter context, so both are equivalent. Read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_queries_and_filters_merged

Comment: Also check this excellent blog article that's just been published: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order